# Limit number of records in a table in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I want to implement in SQLite a table that stores up to 100 records.

The behavior that I am looking for is that the table stores records and when it is full and a new record is added, it deletes the oldest record and writes the new one.

I was reading through the SQLite documentation but I don't find what I am looking for.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to explain something important. Each record has an ID AUTOINCREMENT field. This is how I know which records were written first.

I really can't come up with a solution on how to store only 100 records.

Comment: As noted in an answer, it may not be a good idea, but if you do need this, `CREATE TRIGGER triggername AFTER INSERT ON tablename ...` would probably be the way to go.

Comment: Would you be so kind and explain what is the purpose of this? Being unusual thing to do it is quite likely there is an another, easier, solution to the ultimate problem.

Comment: The memory is quite limited and these records will be written quite often. Just storing every record and read only the las 100 will increase the database size indefinitely.  This table will be a log which stores the last 100 actions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For small tables it is not recommended that you have specified keys anyway, so by default it is indexed on rowid.
Thus rowid defines the order in which the records were added.

For each row added:
`SELECT rowid FROM TheTable limit 1;`
and delete it!
Simplicity itself.
i.e.

`delete from TheTable where rowid in (SELECT rowid FROM TheTable limit 1);`

Thereby, for each record added at the front end, you remove the first record at the back end.

For tables which do have one or more indices just ignore them and order using rowid.

`delete from TheTable where rowid in (SELECT rowid FROM TheTable order by rowid asc limit 1);`

Answering this question allowed me to use this technique to alter my own project, to limit the number of files in a "recently used" file list.

Comment: This really solves my issue considering that I can't store more than 100 records due to size issues.

Comment: In which case, remember to `vacuum` the database on a regular basis. That will keep the size down the indices tight.

Answer (score 5):

It's bad idea.
Better to store all data and get only 100 latest

```
select * from tblmessage order by datefield DSC limit 100
```

Good idea with trigger )

```
    CREATE TRIGGER triggername AFTER INSERT ON tablename
    BEGIN
      delete from tblmessage where 
        datefield =(select min(datefield) from tblmessage ) 
        and (select count(*) from tblmessage )=100;
    END;
```

Comment: Kudos for adding an example `TRIGGER` code.  The OP should be aware (if I'm reading this correctly) that if there were several entries with the same `datefield` value, and that was the minimum, they would all be deleted when the trigger kicks-in (but if the granularity of the date/time field is such that this might happen, and there's nothing else to resolve to a single "oldest" record, there's probably not a lot else it could do).

Comment: First, you either want `=101` in the final test or `> 100` (as written, it will delete a row _when_ there are 100 records after the insert, leaving 99).  I think `> 100` is safer: if you somehow got _more_ than 100 rows, the second version will continue deleting as new records are added, keeping the number fixed.  Using `=` will stop deleting if the count was `101`. Replacing `datefield` with the name of your auto-increment field will do what you want: because the key-field is unique, there will only ever be one match, so only one record will be deleted each time.

Comment: I will give this trigger a try.

I had this one but did't work correctly:
    `CREATE TRIGGER DELETE_TAIL AFTER INSERT ON TABLE`
    `BEGIN`
        `DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ID=NEW.ID%100 AND ID!=NEW.ID;`
    `END`